# I get an error when i run my angular application on visual studio.

Tags: html, angularjs, visual-studio

I created a to do list app using html, css and javascript. I'm trying to create the same app using javascript. The problem I'm facing is that I'm getting this error when I include angular in my application.

```
Angular: disabling automatic bootstrap. <script> protocol indicates an extension, document.location.href does not match.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this could be an IE bug, try bootstrapping your app manually instead of relying on the standard approach with the `ng-app` directive.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {  
 angular.bootstrap(document, ['nameOfYourApp']);
});
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15567

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15772

https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2017/02/01/fix-in-ie-angular-1-6-1-disabling-automatic-bootstrap-script-protocol-indicates-an-extension-document-location-href-does-not-match/

Comment: add the beginning of your javascript code, and remove the ng-app from your html

Comment: I get this error when i run the app as mentioned [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: Add it after your root module definition. i.e. after angular.module("myApp");

Comment: This issue is expected in Firefox only, do like above, (remove directive ng-app, define app, place above fix code to manual bootstrap, then app.run())
the issue disappear but coming a new one like:

Comment: `Error: Assertion failed
Stack trace:
assert@/js/webcomponents.js:116:21
assertIsNodeWrapper@/js/webcomponents.js:1609:7
insertBefore@/js/webcomponents.js:1823:9
appendChild@/js/webcomponents.js:1820:16
replaceWith@/angular.js:10555:9
applyDirectivesToNode@/angular.js:9615:13
compileNodes@/angular.js:9140:15
bootstrapApply/<@/angular.js:1997:11
doBootstrap@/angular.js:1993:5
bootstrap@/angular.js:2013:12
@/js/app-module.js:3:2`